# JPA: duplicate children on saving parent

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using JPA in order to interact with the database.
I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfigRt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String uuid;

    private String ip;

    @Column
    private String fiscalCode;

    private Boolean active;

    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    private LocalDateTime modificationDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "configRt", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<VatRt> vatRtList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "configRt", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<DepartmentRt> departmentRtList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "configRt", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PaymentRt> paymentRtList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "configRt", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OperatorRt> operatorRtList;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<HeaderRt> header;

    @ManyToOne
    private SellPoint sellPoint;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RtXmlVersion xmlVersion;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean enableLottery;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "date default '2021-02-01'")
    private LocalDate startLotteryDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AdvanceType advanceType;
}
```

I'm using this function in order to update the record on the database

```
ConfigRt configRt = new ConfigRt();
// SETTING HERE THE NEW PROPERTIES OF CONFIGRT
configRtRepository.save(configRt)
```

Updating is working, but all the child elements are duplicated inside the database tables. What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT: here the function i use in order to create the new ConfigRT

```
private ConfigRt reverseMappingConfigRt(ConfigRtDto configRtDto) {
    ConfigRt configRt = null != configRtDto.getId() ? configRtRepository.findById(configRtDto.getId()).orElse(new ConfigRt()) : new ConfigRt();
    configRt.setId(configRtDto.getId());
    configRt.setUuid(configRtDto.getUuid());
    configRt.setIp(configRtDto.getIp());
    configRt.setFiscalCode(configRtDto.getFiscalCode());
    configRt.setActive(configRtDto.getActive());
    configRt.setCreationDate(configRtDto.getCreationDate());
    configRt.setModificationDate(configRtDto.getModificationDate());
    if (configRt.getVatRtList() == null) {
        configRt.setVatRtList(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    configRt.getVatRtList().clear();
    configRt.getVatRtList().addAll(configRtDto.getVatList().stream()
            .map(v -> reverseMappingVatRt(v, configRt))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    if (configRt.getPaymentRtList() == null) {
        configRt.setPaymentRtList(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    configRt.getPaymentRtList().clear();
    configRt.getPaymentRtList().addAll(configRtDto.getPaymentRtList().stream()
            .map(p -> reverseMappingPaymentRt(p, configRt)
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    if (configRt.getDepartmentRtList() == null) {
        configRt.setDepartmentRtList(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    configRt.getDepartmentRtList().clear();
    configRt.getDepartmentRtList().addAll(configRtDto.getDepartmentRtList().stream()
            .map(d -> reverseMappingDepartmentRt(d, configRt))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    if (configRt.getOperatorRtList() == null) {
        configRt.setOperatorRtList(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    configRt.getOperatorRtList().clear();
    configRt.getOperatorRtList().addAll(configRtDto.getOperatorRtList().stream()
            .map(o -> reverseMappingOperatorRt(o, configRt))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    configRt.setHeader(configRtDto.getHeader().stream()
            .map(this::reverseMappingHeaderRt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    configRt.setXmlVersion(configRtDto.getXmlVersion());
    configRt.setAdvanceType(configRtDto.getAdvanceType());
    configRt.setEnableLottery(configRtDto.isEnableLottery());
    if (null != configRtDto.getStartLotteryDate())
        configRt.setStartLotteryDate(configRtDto.getStartLotteryDate());
    else
        configRt.setStartLotteryDate(LocalDate.of(2021, 2, 1));
    return configRt;
}
```

Comment: Since one ConfigRt can hage multiple children like VatRt, DepartmentRt, etc then its natural that updating one ConfigRt will add multiple children because you are not handling it. For example, every time you are saving a new list of VatRt on same ConfigRt without merging it with its existing VatRt. You need to merge new List<VatRt> with existing ConfigRt.getVatRt()